# Can any one see if I'm surfing the web via remote control?

Tags: remote-desktop

So, if I'm surfing the web (google etc..), can they see that I'm surfing from my laptop which is remotely connected to my desktop PC?

Or will they only be able to see that my desktop PC is connected to their site? 
I'm currently using teamViewer for remote access to my desktop PC.

Thanks, Jay.

Comment: By "they", do you mean the website, or some adversary who might have a better view of the network?

Comment: By "they", I mean the websites I'm visiting. E.g., Google.com, Facebook.com etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

No one can see that you are using teamviewer unless they have access to the network traffic between your laptop and your desktop pc.
So the answer in most cases would be a big NO. ;)

One exception might be if you are connecting to your desktop PC via the internet, and then make a connection from the desktop PC back to the router your laptop is connected to.
It *might* be possible for an ISP or the admin of the network your desktop PC are connected to, to examine firewall logs and put two and two together, but that is far fetched. Most remote access traffic are (or should be) encrypted anyway, so the chance of someone figuring it out are next to non-existing.

Answer (score 1):

When you remote to a computer and perform actions on the remote computer, it acts kind of like a proxy.  The request doesn't come from the actual computer you are using, but rather you are using the computer that is with you to instruct another computer to access a site.

From the perspective of that site, it is just the computer you are controlling involved.  It has no idea about the remote control.